# View size and owner on folders, within a folder

Tags: linux, disk-usage, ownership

Anyone know how to view all the folders within an directory with size, folder/file, owner?

The only command I know of is `du -hs *`
But that shows all the subfolders aswell and does not show owner.

For example,
I would like to get the info size, folder/file, owner of the folder/file under "/my/path/".

Any know of command which could provide me with this info?

Br
Hultman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `find` command:

```
find /my/path -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%u %g   " -exec du -h --max-depth=0 {} \;
```

should locate all directories (filter `-type d`) one level below the starting point `/my/path` (option `-maxdepth 1`). It will then

- use the `-printf` option to print owner and group, and then
- invoke `du --max-depth=0` on each directory found (`{}`) to print the name and total size directly behind the output of the preceding `-printf` option, using the `-exec` mechanism.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for!

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here I've got a simple snippet for you

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unset fname owner size i

for f in "$@"
  do
    fname[i]="$f"
    owner[i]=$(stat -c %U "$f")
    size[i++]=$(stat -c %s "$f")
  done 

for i in "${!fname[@]}"
  do
    printf "User %s owns %s and the size is %d Kbytes\n" "${owner[i]}" "${fname[i]}" $((${size[i]} / 1024))
  done
```

Make the script executable or run it like  `bash script_name [path]`

```
chmod u+x script_name
```

And run it

```
./script_name /my/path/*
```